# How to fix stud drilled from the side?

Tags: walls, studs

The plumber I hired to install a new washer box drilled a bunch of chunks off one of the studs in my wall. The chunks taken off are from the left side of the stud when looking straight at the wall.[image]

From reading the [International Residential Code](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.6), I assume this is not up to code.
But what can be done to fix it? I'm more worried about the structural integrity of things.

**edit:**
Here is some more information. I studied how the walls connected. I think the perpendicular stud is actually connecting to an exterior wall.
[image]

Comment: Are you referring to Section R602.6 regarding notching and drilling of studs?

Comment: Did you see Section R602.6 is for exterior walls and load bearing walls only? Is this notch in either of those?

Comment: Yes, referring to R602.6. There are requirements for interior non load bearing walls too.

Comment: Yes, but is this in an exterior wall or load bearing wall?

Comment: It's an interior wall. I'm not 100% sure if it's load bearing.

Comment: Is your house 1 story or 2. Does this occur on the main floor? Does the roof framing rest on top of this wall?

Comment: It's a 2-story house and this laundry room is on the 1st floor. The wall is shared with the kitchen where the fridge is. There is a bedroom above the laundry room.

I'm not very sure about the framing.

Comment: Does the second floor joists or roof joists rest on this wall? Can you send a picture of the attic above this wall?  Can you send a picture of the framing at the top of this wall?

Comment: Based on your drawing, that drilled stud is not in an exterior wall. We still don’t know if it’s a bearing wall, but it’s definitely not an exterior wall.

Answer (score 3):

I see other studs hard against that stud.  this part of the wall
is probably still stronger than it ever needed to be.

Comment: Yeah, that stud to the right of the notched one looks like it's for a wall that goes perpendicular into the backside of the washer box wall- you can see the yellow wire bend into it. So notched stud already has a stud sistered to it, albiet at 90 degrees. Which also means you can't sister another stud to it since it won't fit. I'd just leave it alone and move on with life

Comment: I agree. There's nothing to fix here.

Comment: I thought that was strange. I thought studs are supposed to be 16 inches apart, but the notched stud has a perpendicular stud and then another stud parallel to it.

What might even requires something like this in the first place?

Comment: As Jamie M notes, that's a common arrangement to make a   junction of walls one stud to make a join between the walls and three more studs to hold the edges of the drywall.

Comment: I studied some more how the walls connect and edited the original post to add a picture. I think that perpendicular stud is actually connecting an exterior wall. Does that change things?

Comment: no, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could sister another 2x4 on the right side. Extend 2x4 sister all the way down to the plate if it's load bearing .[image: 2x4 sister]

Comment: The sister may run into a problem with the 12g romex cable that's below the notch though.  I suppose the sister could itself be slightly notched to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's not to IBC and it's a load bearing wall, one compromised stud won't make the house fall down.  You might get a little sag in the floor and roof above.

If you want to fix it, since the wall is open with the drywall removed, you could just sister another stud next to the damaged one.  I see you'll have to notch it to accommodate the yellow electrical cable that goes through it.  (Not to give you more headaches, but that doesn't look like it's compliant either...)  Attach it to the existing stud with a few construction screws, it doesn't look like there's room to swing a hammer easily.

Comment: You won't get measurable sag unless the stud was to completely collapse at the notch, which it won't.